# Pass data from server after mutation onSuccess React Query

Tags: reactjs, react-query

Wondering if anyone can help with the below problem or point me in the right direction?
I am doing a POC as we may move to RQ. I am stuck on how to pass data from a mutation.

I am fetching data from an API. I then fetch a specific user via an ID. What I want to achieve is that when the name of the user is changed, a mutation takes place  (which is currently successful) and the user's name changes.  How do I pass back, and update the data after OnSuccess?

I have hardcoded the user name for testing purposes. And here is a sandbox.

Here is a sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/fast-bird-4p1u08?file=/src/components/User/User.js

Edit: I can't use invalidateQueries or refetch as the problem is that when a put request is made, the resource will not be really updated on the server but it will be faked as if. So I receive the response, but I can't then refetch as the user hasn't been updated (as per the docs) https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/guide/

Comment: You should search the react-query docs for invalidateQueries, setQueryData, and refetch. One of these will probably be what you're looking for.

Comment: The problem is that when a put request is made, the resource will not be really updated on the server but it will be faked as if. So I receive the response, but I can't then refetch as the user hasn't been updated (as per the docs) https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/guide/

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly there are two things you can do that i know of .

**1, optimistic updates**

```
const queryClient = useQueryClient() // import useQueryClient

useMutation(updateTodo, {
  // When mutate is called:
  onMutate: async newTodo => {
    // Cancel any outgoing refetches (so they don't overwrite our optimistic update)
    await queryClient.cancelQueries(['todos'])

    // Snapshot the previous value
    const previousTodos = queryClient.getQueryData(['todos'])

    // Optimistically update to the new value
    queryClient.setQueryData(['todos'], old => [...old, newTodo])

    // Return a context object with the snapshotted value
    return { previousTodos }
  },
  // If the mutation fails, use the context returned from onMutate to roll back
  onError: (err, newTodo, context) => {
    queryClient.setQueryData(['todos'], context.previousTodos)
  },
  // Always refetch after error or success:
  onSettled: () => {
    queryClient.invalidateQueries(['todos'])
  },
})
```

this will not request new data but you can just take the value you sent on mutation and update the cache.

**2, query invalidation.**
you have to import the useQueryClient as above

```
let queryClient = useQueryClient()
```

then on success, you can call the invalidateQueries() function to trigger
a data refresh you need to pass the query key like ["query-key"] in order for RQ to know what data it needs to refetch

```
queryClient.invalidateQueries()
```

both have their use cases in my opinion but can be interchangeably used most of the time